# Gentoo Gnome 3.2 Wireless "Connecting..."

Tags: gnome, wifi, gentoo, networkmanager

I recently updated my Gentoo with GNOME 2.x to GNOME 3.2. My NetworkManager applet refuses to connect to my network; however, it does not give an error as it simply hangs as "Connecting..."

I checked `/var/log/messages` and it seems that NetworkManager is simply not performing Step 5 of 5 to connect to the network. I am given an IP Address lease when it completes step 4... But step 5 is never started.